# Conversion of csv to xls using C# on basis of semicolons

Tags: asp.net

In this Code I am getting some error that class factory is not available. The Program is about converting csv(comma separated Values) file int xls(Microsoft Excel) file on the basis of semicolons. Can anybody help me out in it.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
namespace ReadWriteCSV
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = workBook.ActiveSheet;

            string fullPath = @"D:\Work\Sep-14\ReadWriteCSV\ReadWriteCSV\File\diff_16122014095440.csv";
            string[] fileRows = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath, Encoding.UTF8);

            foreach (string rows in fileRows)
            {
                var columns = rows.Split(';');

                for (int j = 0; j < fileRows.Length; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
                    {
                        List<string> elements = new List<string>();
                        foreach (string col in columns)
                        {
                            elements.Add(col);
                            sheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = col;
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            workBook.SaveAs(@"D:\Work\Sep-14\ReadWriteCSV\ReadWriteCSV\File\WriteXls.xlsx");
            workBook.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open csv file using Excel and save it as xlsx

Comment: I have done the same thing. Please suggest some other solution or find the error in the above program

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following:

Excel index columns using letters not numbers such as A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H, ...etc.

You will need to convert the numeric index to letter index. You can use ASCII as an offset if you don't have columns more than 26 columns.

```
sheet.Cells[i + 1, ((char)(j+ 65)).ToString()] = col; //65 is ASCII for letter A
```

EDIT:

Your code has another problem. Why are you iterating through columns again inside the inner loop? The same with the outer foreach loop. All the code you need is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< fileRows.length;i++)
{
   string row = fileRows[i];
   string[] columns = row.Split(';');
   for (int j =0; j<columns.length;j++)
      sheet.Cells[i + 1, ((char)(j+ 65)).ToString()] = columns[j];
}
```

And that's it. You don't need to write the inner loop as it will cost you a lot of useless processing.